# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in genexus

Tags: genexus, genexus-gam, workwithplus

Does anyone encountered this error when you're commiting your changes into genexus server?

It looks like it's related to the WorkWithPlus pattern but the project was newly created and I haven't apply any pattern yet.

Here's the screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What WorkWithPlus for Web version are you using?

We suggest upgrading to WorkWithPlus for Web 14 Upgrade #3.2, where we have fixed that issue: https://docs.workwithplus.com/com.wiki.wiki?4268,Issues+Resolved+%28v14+Upgrade+%233.2%29,

You can download it from our Developer Center: developer.workwithplus.com

Comment: Hi @Sofia, can you check this one too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70470431/genexus-server-user-control-dvelop-workwithplusutilities-f5-is-used-by-some-o

Comment: Sure! I've posted an answer. Please remember, you can get further assistance by our support channels: https://workwithplus.com/support