# GeneXus Server: User control 'DVelop.WorkWithPlusUtilities_F5' is used by some object(s) but is not installed in this GeneXus instance

Tags: genexus, workwithplus

Does anyone encountered this error when you're commiting your changes into genexus server?

It looks like it's related to the WorkWithPlus pattern but the project was newly created and just applied WW+ using design wizard.

Here's the screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install WorkWithPlus for Web on your GxServer too. It seems that hasn't been properly installed.

To install it, you should run the same setup that you installed locally and check the option "GeneXus Server Installation" during the setup process. You can read more details [here](https://docs.workwithplus.com/com.wiki.wiki?4140,Installing%20WorkWithPlus%20in%20GeneXus%20Server).

Comment: Hi @Sofia, thanks for your quick response. Can we also use the trial version in Genexus Server?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. You don't need an extra licence for GxServer.